# Array Job on LSF: Setting Seed?

Tags: r, random-seed, slurm, lsf

I'm running a standard statistical simulation to split e.g. 10000 iterations (each with different random seed) among say 100 array nodes.

I've done this many times in the past and always received the desired results, however, this time all 100 nodes produced exactly the same results, as if they all had the same random seed. Is there something subtle in LSF that can set everything to the same seed?

I'm running R jobs and I'm not setting seeds in R. I realize one solution is to set the seed in R from the job index in the array, but I'm just trying to figure out what happened. BTW I know that the scheduler did not start all of the jobs simultaneously.

Here's a minimal example: (all 10 output files are identical)

array.test.sim.job

```
#BSUB-J test[1-10]
#BSUB-o Rout/sim%I.out
#BSUB-W 12:00
#BSUB-q short

module load stats/R/3.2.1

R CMD BATCH --no-save arraytest.R Rout/sim${LSB_JOBID}${LSB_JOBINDEX}.Rout
```

arraytest.R

```
write.csv(rnorm(100), file = paste('rnorms', Sys.Date(), ',', format(Sys.time(), "%H.%M.%S"), '.txt', sep = ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by a stray .Rdata file that had appeared in the working directory. Deleting this file, or using the flag --no-restore solved the problem.

Comment: Was it just a plain `.RData` (ie nothing in the *), so that your R session loaded it and got the `.Random.seed` from that?